# how to assign values to one of 2d arryas?

Tags: c

I want some 2d array

```
const int a = 5;
const int b = 10;
double R[a][b];
```

then I want to assign 5 numbers: {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6} to [a] index of the R 2d array. Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean 'to [a] index' - please show what you have tried

Comment: What values do you want to assign to the second dimension?

Comment: second dimension won't have any values. The problem resulted from my trying of dividing some h[a][b]/y[a] with y[a] ={0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6}. Getting the value of h[a] run in a loop for Tgraph worked, but I want to specifically divide that h[a]/y[a], but it gives me error. So assigning y[a][b] = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6} worked, but it gives me hesitation that if I run h[a]/y[a] in Tgraph loop, what value it is really using, Hence, I need to specifically assign those values to y[a] index. In the question R[a] index. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: "second dimension won't have any values" .. It will have _something_, indeterminate values if you don't initialize them. What's `h`? What's `y`? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable-sized arrays, where the lengths are computed at runtime, you cannot use an initializer. If there is a pattern in the initial values you typically use a *for* loop. On the other hand, if the lengths can be computed at compile-time you can instead use an array initializer. Here are examples of both cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(array) ((int) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0]))

int main(void)
{
    const int a = 10, b = 5;
    double R[a][b];
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN(R); i++) {
        R[i][0] = 0.2;
        R[i][1] = 0.3;
        R[i][2] = 0.4;
        R[i][3] = 0.5;
        R[i][4] = 0.6;
    }

    double R1[][10] ={
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6},
        {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6}};

    return 0;
}
```

Note: By computing the length of *R* with the sizeof operator, instead of using length variables (*a* and *b*) used in its declaration, the logic becomes less fragile. To get the number of columns in the example you use `LEN(R[0])`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the first one with loop worked for me. Though, LEN gives me error saying undeclared. So, I used b instead of LEN(R)

Comment: @Thefirstman You need to define the LEN macro like I do above.